# Using Cordova and Phonegap Push Plugin get invalidRegistration on app server when push to iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I used [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs) instruction on Google Cloud Messaging site to set certificates for APNS. I'm on development phase and set only development certificate in Apple Developer Console.
Then I set up [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and initialized it in JS like that (on deviceready of course):

```
var pushController = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
      "senderID": "_",
      "forceShow": true
    },
    "ios": {
      "alert": "true",
      "badge": "true",
      "sound": "true"
    }
  });

pushController.on('registration', function (data) {
  console.log("Push registration", data);
});
```

So when registration is successful I see registration id of the device in console. But when I try to push message from server to this registration id I get error response with code invalidRegistration. I'm pushing from node.js server with [gcm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcm).

Same setup works great on Android. I wasn't sure about correctness of certificates and repeated process strictly following instructions. But result on iOS is the same.

Comment: invalidRegistration is basically due to invalid access token. have you tried checking the "to" value of the http request  and checked it against the one that the device received during registration?

Answer (score 0):

As it heppens best way to solve the problem is to recheck every stage of process 100th time. The problem was in server side sertificate. It wasn't the same as the one that app and apns used.

Now I have problem with ad hoc production version but that's another story.